# How to center and move down some text?

Tags: html, css, alignment, block, center

I'm trying to center the bottom navigation bar with

```
#main-nav{ margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;}
```

But it is not working. I even did `<center></center>` in the html file and it is not centering.

This is how it looks like: http://jsfiddle.net/EZJwM/8/

I think it has something to do with the `&copy; 2012 Bin.xxx, All Rights Reserved` and that it is in the same block or something. Can someone help me?

Comment: try specifying a width to the container element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this :

> display:inline-block;*display:block;zoom:1;text-align:center;

Comment: In case you wonder what is that *display:block;zoom:1; it's for funny people who likes to use old school browsers such as IE7.
Glad it did work !

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#main-nav{ margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;text-align:center}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this markup and css

```
<section class="container"><nav id="main-nav">&copy; 2012 Bin.xxx, All Rights Reserved</nav></section>

.container { width: 100%}
#main-nav{ width:50%; margin: 0 auto;}
```

hope it will help you!